# Jquery Tabs Showing As Bullet List

Tags: jquery, tabs

In my web app I am using jquery to generate a tabs area where I can retrieve a list of students.  For some reason, the tabs are not showing up and instead it is giving me a bullet list.

I've looked at a couple of the answers for this problem from earlier days and have implemented what was suggested (I think) but still nothing.

It all works on another web app I have running on the same server

```
       <link     rel="stylesheet"href="/../../../code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jque    ry-ui.css">
  <script src="/../../../code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="/../../../code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
  });
  </script>
   <style>
         #tabs{font-size: 14px;}
         .ui-widget-header {
            background:#b9cd6d;
            border: 1px solid #A7C942;
            width:600;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            font-weight: bold;
         }
     </style>
```

The HTML for the actual tabs

```
    <div id="tabs" align="center" width="700">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="listseniors.php">Seniors</a></li>
    <li><a href="listjuniors.php">Juniors</a></li>
    <li><a href="listsophomores.php">Sophomores</a></li>
    <li><a href="listfreshmen.php">Freshmen</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    </div>
  <div id="tabs-4">
    </div>
</div>

<div id="student_data" align="center"></div>
```

I've compared the code to the other app and it looks identical so I'm at a loss as to what to check next.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the CSS for jQuery UI is loading? Your paths for JS and CSS seem... interesting.

Comment: Your paths to jQuery and jQueryUI don't look right. They're relative, yet you include the domain in the path...?

Comment: In one of my tests I included a path I found in one of the answers here, but that didn't help, so I went back to the way the other app is.  And yes it does look strange...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works when using these links

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/66eoc1md/1

```js
$(function() {
  $("#tabs").tabs();
});
```

```css
 #tabs {
   font-size: 14px;
 }
 
 .ui-widget-header {
   background: #b9cd6d;
   border: 1px solid #A7C942;
   width: 600;
   color: #FFFFFF;
   font-weight: bold;
 }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<div id="tabs" align="center" width="700">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Seniors</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Juniors</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Sophomores</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-4">Freshmen</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">1
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">2
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">3
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-4">4
  </div>
</div>

<div id="student_data" align="center"></div>
```

---

Edit:
I also fixed the `a href=`

Comment: It may be due to the spaces in `smoothness/jque    ry-ui.css` in the first line of your question or to other path issues.

Comment: One quick question, now that it works and I can test, it seems that each tab works once, but not a second time, Should I make this a separate question?

Comment: that is an other issue indeed

Comment: Rats, that's what I was afraid of, oh well let research it before I post it thanks